# Missing mysql.sock file. phpMyAdmin - Fedora 17

Tags: mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, fedora, webmin

I run Fedora 17 with "Webadmin". So I tried to use webadmin option to update upload maximum size to my MySQL database. Now, I not able to restart mysqld. I have no GUI, so when run `systemctl status mysqld.service` I gives me this message:

```
[root@localhost ~]# systemctl status mysqld.service
mysqld.service - MySQL database server
          Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled)
          Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon, 30 Jul 2012 15:08:26 -0400; 6min ago
         Process: 3560 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysqld-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
         Process: 3559 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
         Process: 3542 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysqld-prepare-db-dir (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
          CGroup: name=systemd:/system/mysqld.service

Jul 30 15:08:23 localhost mysqld_safe[3559]: 120730 15:08:23 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysqld.log'.
Jul 30 15:08:23 localhost mysqld_safe[3559]: 120730 15:08:23 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
```

or when I try to access my phpmyadmin screen i see this message:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error
#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured).
```

When I run in terminal `locate mysql.sock` it shows the correct path `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`.
But when I run this command `ls /var/lib/mysql`, I not able to locate this file.

Please help.

Comment: You may try "getenforce" to see weather "SELinux" is enable. If may cause unexpected problem.
If it is enabled, try "setenforce 0" to disable it. For more information, click this [URL](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/red-hat-fedora-linux/187866-mysql-not-starting-fedora-16-a.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After punching my monitor and kicking my server I was able to find a fix. Not sure how safe or good at is, but it works to me.

In terminal open up your my.cnf file `# nano /etc/my.cnf`

Delete or just comment all existing settings with '#', then just paste this code that I found on http://blog.mclaughlinsoftware.com/2011/12/07/fixing-my-cnf-on-fedora/

```
[mysqld]
# Settings user and group are ignored when systemd is used.
# If you need to run mysqld under different user or group,
# customize your systemd unit file for mysqld according to the
# instructions in http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Systemd

# Default directory.
datadir=/var/lib/mysql

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server listens on.
port=3306

# The Linux Socket the MySQL Server uses when not using a listener.
# socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

# The default storage engine that will be used when creating new tables.
default-storage-engine=INNODB

# Set the SQL mode to strict.
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

# Set the maximum number of connections.
max_connections=100

# Set the number of open tables for all threads.
table_cache=256

# Set the maximum size for internal (in-memory) temporary tables.
tmp_table_size=26M

# Set how many threads should be kept in a cache for reuse.
thread_cache_size=8

# MyISAM configuration.
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=52M
key_buffer_size=36M
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
sort_buffer_size=256K

# InnoDB configuration.
innodb_data_home_dir=/var/lib/mysql
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=2M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_log_buffer_size=1M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=25M
innodb_log_file_size=5M
innodb_thread_concurrency=8

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Open for any comments or suggestions. 
Thank you.